# The application of Squeeze Theorem to find the limit of a trigonometric problem

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I've been learning Squeeze Theorem (and limits in general), but am having problems understanding how to apply it. I understand the basics of the theorem (I think), but I've come across a problem that I'm not even sure how to start solving. I realize that Squeeze Theorem is the way to solve it, but beyond that, I'm clueless.

I've search around the site, and a few other places online, but I can't seem to find a similar problem.

So, here's my problem:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3 - \sin(e^x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2}}$$

Looks easy enough, but I'm clearly missing something obvious. How do we approach a problem like this? I'd love to show my work, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: The limit is $\frac {3-\sin (1)} {\sqrt 2}$. Why does one apply squeeze theorem in this case?

Comment: There was a problem in my formatting, which @pointguardo kindly corrected.

Comment: the answer is still $\frac{3 - \sin(1)}{\sqrt{2}}$ though

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying. Thanks. The answer makes sense, but I have no clue how to get to it. Could this be solved at all with Squeeze Theorem? Or am I totally on the wrong track?

Comment: just plug in $x = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, I get that, but the problem is that I'm trying to learn Squeeze Theorem and this came up in one of my exercises, so solving by subsitution is not going to help in achieving my goal. Naturally, if it's impossible to solve by Squeeze Theorem, then I get that and I've been wasting the past few days attempting to do so.

Comment: @plt27Are you sure that you didn't want to know the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @Narlin That would make more sense, actually, but no, definitely 0. I saw this question in my textbook, and I also found an identical question on an old exam paper (where it explicitly states to use Squeeze Theorem). Plugging in 0 does make the most sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

After my best attempts, I believe this is the most appropriate answer to my question.

The problem cannot be solved by Squeeze Theorem, because:

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 2}} \leq \frac{3 - \sin{(e^{x})}}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 2}} \leq \frac{4}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 2}}$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{2}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 2}} \neq \lim_{x\to0} \frac{4}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 2}}$$